# ConcurrentModificationException while displaying chats in recyclerView

Tags: android, firebase, exception

I am displaying chats in fragment through firebase but it gives ConcurrentModificationException error.

[image: LOGCAT ERROR]

Below is the code in which error is occuring.

CODE:

```
public void readChats() {
    mUsers = new ArrayList<>();
    reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
    reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            mUsers.clear();
            for (DataSnapshot snapshots: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                User user = snapshots.getValue(User.class);
                for (String id :usersList) {
                    if (user.getID().equals(id)) {
                        if (mUsers.size()!=0) {
                            for (User user1 : mUsers) {
                                if (!user.getID().equals(user1.getID())) {
                                    mUsers.add(user);
                                }
                            }
                        } else {
                            mUsers.add(user);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            userAdapter = new adapter(getContext(), mUsers);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(userAdapter);
        }
```

[image: Code picture where error is occuring]

Comment: it can't occur on the place where the cursor is. SHow the line

Comment: If you consider at some point in time to try using [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/), here you can find a tutorial on how to create a complete and functional [Firestore Chat App](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLn2n4GESV0Ak1HiH0tTPTJXsOEy-5v9qb).

Answer (score 1):

If you're looping over a Collection via its Iterator (like in a for(var : collection) loop ), you can't change that collection while you do so.  Doing so is a ConcurrentModification, and invalidates the iterator.

In addition, your code would be broken anyway.  If the last item in mUsers isn't user1, it would infinite loop even if it concurrent modifications were allowed.